# How to put circles filling table cells, ideally that do not get printed?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

I'm wanting to print labels for bottle caps in my home-brewing. I've bought some 19mm label sheets and have a MSWord template which is basically a 9x13 table.

Space is at a premium and I need to make sure I don't put anything in the square cell which will be outside the bounds of the circular label.

Assuming the cell is exactly the width/height of the label, how can I add a circle to each cell as a visual guide so I can check all the printable content wi llbe printed on the label correctly? I do not want the circle to interfere with the text and ideally the circle wouldn't even be printed at all - although this last part is not essential.

Obviously, I don't want to have to do this 117 times!